# Run some functionality before all test suites in Protractor

Tags: protractor, end-to-end

Is it possible to run some tests or a logical flow before any suite in Protractor is run?

For example, I want to break up my Protractor tests into a series of suites for testing different aspects of my application. Let's say Jenkins is going to run the entire test suite before deployment, but individual developers will run only the suites pertinent to the work they're doing.

But I want most of my suites to be able to login to the application, and I'd rather not repeat that login logic in every suite. Is there a way to have a pre-suite test that does stuff like logging in before all tests are run?

I thought about just listing this where I'm defining my suites in my Protractor config like

```
suites: {
  'my-profile': [
    './e2e/login/login-as-customer.e2e-spec.js',
    './e2e/my-profile/my-profile-change-password.e2e-spec.js',
    './e2e/my-profile/my-profile-change-username.e2e-spec.js'
  ],
  'my-contacts': [
    './e2e/login/login-as-customer.e2e-spec.js',
    './e2e/my-contacts/add-contact.e2e-spec.js',
    './e2e/my-contacts/remove-contact.e2e-spec.js'
  ]
}
```

But the problem is I don't want it to have to relogin each time when we run the entire test suite together, or if a developer wants to run more than one suite together. What I need is a pre-suite step somehow.

Is this possible with Protractor?

Comment: You can't use `beforeAll()` in your specs to login?

Comment: I think that would still cause the login to occur before every test suite, even when run together. I'm talking about doing this before all test suites, not before all specs.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the `onPrepare()` function in your conf file. The function is run before the test suites. Here is an example taken from https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/withLoginConf.js

```
onPrepare: function() {
    browser.driver.get(env.baseUrl + '/ng1/login.html');

    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('username')).sendKeys('Jane');
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password')).sendKeys('1234');
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('clickme')).click();

    // Login takes some time, so wait until it's done.
    // For the test app's login, we know it's done when it redirects to
    // index.html.
    return browser.driver.wait(function() {
      return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
        return /index/.test(url);
      });
    }, 10000);
  }
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify one `onPrepare` for some test suites and a different `onPrepare` for others? For example, if some tests need to login with one type of account, and others need to login with a different one?

Comment: Not really, no. For this I would recommend having separate conf file for each test suite.

Comment: You could use the params object in conf.js to provide test run specific data like account login or password etc. Access them by using - browser.params.login.email - for the param object defined as - params: {
    login: {
      email: 'default',
      password: 'default'
    }
  }     https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts   https://moduscreate.com/protractor_parameters_adding_flexibility_automation_tests/

Comment: @A.Duff what I've done is to create a new browser for the each user and keep all user interaction in the same test suites.

Comment: @Grasshopper I believe the full guide to implement what you have posited is here: https://moduscreate.com/blog/protractor-parameters-adding-flexibility-automation-tests/